# keyPressed Listener produces strange behaviour

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I have a series of Text- and Comboboxes along a jTable. I use the input from the boxes to filter the results of a JPQL-query, which are displayed on the jTable. Now, the idea was to automate the process, so that every time the user types a character in a box, the app sends the query automatically and updates the jTable with the filtered results. I tried doing it like this:

```
public class MyKeyListener extends KeyAdapter{
   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt){
      setFilters();
      displayResults(); }}
```

setFilters() and displayResults() are the methods that respectively set the parameters and the query and get the ResultList and update the jTable. I then added the keyPressed to all relevant Textboxes, along with some System.out.println lines for debugging. What happens is following: when i enter the first character  nothing happens. If i enter a second character the KeyListener works and sends the query, but filters only with the second character, the first one is ignored. That´s my first weirdness. The second one is, looking at my console i realized the query is beeing sent 6 times for every for every succesful Key Listened. Help would be greatly appreciated. On second thought, I´m also inserting my setFilters() and displayResults().

```
  private void setFilters() {

    //Auslesen der gesetzten Filter
    String name=jName.getText()+"%";
    String vorname= jVorname.getText()+"%";
    String vvname= jVName.getText()+"%";
    String vvorname=jVVorname.getText()+"%";
    String mname=jMName.getText()+"%";
    String strasse=jAdresse.getText()+"%";
    String plz=jPlz.getText()+"%";
    String ort=jOrt.getText()+"%";
    String gruppe=jGruppe.getText()+"%";
    String geschlecht=(String) jGeschlecht.getSelectedItem()+"%";
    String mvorname=jMVorname.getText()+"%";
    String firma=jFirma.getText()+"%";



    //Die Query
    kinderQuery = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : rcwPUEntityManager.createQuery("SELECT k FROM Kinder k "
            + "INNER JOIN k.vaeter vat "
            + "INNER JOIN k.muetter mut "
            + "INNER JOIN k.gruppen gru "
            + "INNER JOIN k.firmen fir "
            + "WHERE k.kindName LIKE :name "
            + "AND k.kindVorname LIKE :vorname "
            + "AND vat.vaterName LIKE :vname "
            + "AND vat.vaterVorname LIKE :vvorname "
            + "AND mut.mutterName LIKE :mname "
            + "AND mut.mutterVorname LIKE :mvorname "
            + "AND k.kindStrasse LIKE :strasse "
            + "AND k.kindPLZ LIKE :plz "
            + "AND k.kindOrt LIKE :ort "
            + "AND gru.gruppeName LIKE :gruppe "
            + "AND k.kindGeschlecht LIKE :geschlecht "
            + "AND fir.firmaName LIKE :firma ");


           //Einsetzen der ausgelesenen Strings in die JPQL-Query Parameter
    kinderQuery.setParameter("name", name);
    kinderQuery.setParameter("vorname", vorname);
    kinderQuery.setParameter("vname", vvname);
    kinderQuery.setParameter("vvorname", vvorname);
    kinderQuery.setParameter("mname", mname);
    kinderQuery.setParameter("mvorname", mvorname);
    kinderQuery.setParameter("strasse", strasse);
    kinderQuery.setParameter("plz", plz);
    kinderQuery.setParameter("ort", ort);
    kinderQuery.setParameter("gruppe", gruppe);
    kinderQuery.setParameter("geschlecht", geschlecht);
    kinderQuery.setParameter("firma", firma);

}

 private void displayResults(){
    java.util.Collection data = kinderQuery.getResultList();
    System.out.println(data);
    kinderList.clear();
    kinderList.addAll(data);
    jTable1.repaint();
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the Document used by the text field has not been updated when the keyPressed event is generated. You could listen for the keyTyped event, however I don't recommend this as it is not the best solution and Swing provides a better API to use.

The better way to do this is to use a DocumentListener which is specifically designed for this purpose. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a Document Listener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for an example and explanation.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. I admit never having used the DocumentListener, I´ll read it through.

Answer (score 0):

Here's pretty much how to do it. A couple of benefits for you using this approach instead of the `keyPressed` is that it will work also when you paste some text into the fields and it's easy to avoid doing all your filtering on deletes etc.

```
// in your frame or panel
Document doc = new PlainDocument();
doc.addDocumentListener(new MyDocumentListener());

JTextField textField = new JTextField(15);
textField.setDocument(doc);

add(textField);

private class MyDocumentListener implements DocumentListener
{
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent)
    {
        // Do your stuff here
        System.out.println("insert detected!");
    }

    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent)
    {
        // ignore this
    }

    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent)
    {
        // ignore this
    }
}
```

And to avoid doing search and filter round trips on every weird thing your users might input into the text fields you should consider doing your own implementation of PlainDocument that only accepts certain characters.

```
private class MyDocument extends PlainDocument
{
    @Override
    public void insertString(int offs, String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(getText(0, getLength()));
        builder.insert(offs, str);

        if (builder.toString().matches("[A-Za-z]*"))
        {
            super.insertString(offs, str, a);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The Swing tutorial provides and explanation as well as a working example. Why do you think posting a few fragments of code that don't do anything is better than the tutorial? Also, from the section in the Swing tutorial on "Text Compnent Features" you will find a section on using a Document Filter which is the preferred approach for filtering/editing text as it is typed. Or you can even use a JFormattedTextField.

Comment: I've not proclaimed it is better, it's still a good idea to read the tutorial and I was also the one that upped your answer. However often you don't need a whole tutorial to solve one particular problem, it's a lot of noise. It's also very convenient to get a concrete example tailored to the question at hand and get a couple of benefits for this particular case pointed out. Can't you agree?

Comment: I never suggested you read the whole tutorial, only the section that shows how to write a DocumentListener. You did NOT post a concrete example since your code is just a few random lines that are not compileable. Your code is NOT tailered to the question. In general it is not necessary to spoon feed the answer when the tutorial has a general solution. This way it forces the posted to understand the example rather than just copy code and not understand it. "Give somebody a fish and they eat for a day. Teach somebody to fish and they eat for life".

Comment: Jeez.. listen to yourself. I won't argue back at the marking words level so here are my final words: Not everyone appreciates the "link to tutorial" kind of answers, it can be a big hurdle for a novice that they have "a general solution" and not a specific one. The tutorial is not gonna say "if one would, like you are, trigger a search on every change of the Document you should consider filtering the user input to avoid doing unnecessary searches and here's a way to do it! <code example of just that>". I don't want SO to be a tutorial registry.

Comment: Actually, i did both. I used the code AND read the tutorial. Not that I´m the diplomatic type, but i do really appreciate both kinds of help. I love the quick and dirty code snippet i can immediately paste into my code, but i´m also the type that will read the F***ing manual, eventually :)....which i already did, in this case. Thanks guys.

Comment: @Oskar Lund, my comment was about the DocumentListener code. There was no need to duplicate that code here because it was fully covered in the tutorial. Your code to filter for valid characters was NOT part of the question. As such it should be listed as a helpful tip or suggestion, not an answer to the question. Also, extending a PlainDocumen (while it works) is NOT the preferred solution. Since JDK4, you would use a DocumentFilter for this type of filtering or maybe a JFormattedTextField. If you read the tutorial you will find an example.

Comment: You really like to capitalize the word "not" don't you? :) Jokes aside, thing is I saw it as part of the OP's problem that his searches were posted too many times and tried to help with that too. You're of course right about the DocumentFilter. And about using comments instead of answers sometimes (although code can't be formatted in comments), and I'm aware of that and will start doing it as soon as I have 5 more rep points on here....